# SPARQL: array-strings conversion / extraction

Tags: arrays, sparql, ontology

I am doing a SPARQL Query that for one variable gives me the output `"[-1.6101874126499998e-19]"`. This is obviously a string containing an array (that could also contain more numbers). Is there a way to access the number in it or does it need to be done in the underlying graph?

If it needs to be changed in the graph, what is a good ontological way to create multi-dimensional arrays...?

Comment: here is some recent blog post regarding 1-dim arrays in RDF: https://ontola.io/blog/ordered-data-in-rdf/ - not sure about n-dim arrays. Never had to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsd:float(SUBSTR(?var,2,STRLEN(?var)-2))` does the job in this case, but it's quite hacky :/

Comment: why is this hacky? SPARQL resp. RDF do not provide a native datatype for arrays, so without custom function in the triple store this is the obvious way to get the data out of this RDF literal of datatype string.

Comment: For a longer list like ``"[1,2,3,4,5]"`` I would have to write this similarly 5 times to get the values, not to speak of arrays with an arbitrary length... :/
Thanks for your answer though. I assume there is nothing like loops in SPARQL?

Comment: No, there is not. If you're using triples stores like Apache Jena or GraphDB, you could write your own custom functions.